# unable to install from terminal

Tags: apt

Everytime I install any software or update i get this message as below:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude:2: Extra junk at end of file
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: maybe you tell us what you type in :) ?

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo cat  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude`

Comment: @Jan `sudo` is not needed there. Please try to avoid unnecessary usage of `sudo`.