# What's wrong with using sudo?

Tags: sudo, security

In a comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545562/unable-to-install-from-terminal?noredirect=1#comment747596_545562) I've been told that unnecessarily using `sudo` should be avoided. While it wasn't needed in that particular case, I don't see any harm in using it.

I think that when executing trivial programs like `cat` as root using `sudo`, the overall risk of hitting a bug that would somehow compromise system security is very low.

So can someone please point out the possible implications, besides typing 4 more characters and a space?

Comment: "Note that if I can get you to "su and say" something just by asking,
you have a very serious security problem on your system and you should
look into it."
(By Paul Vixie, vixie-cron 3.0.1 installation notes)

Comment: [Community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) also says: **"You could type a command incorrectly and destroy the system"**

Comment: When writing this question I unintentionally forgot to exclude poor consciousness or utter stupidity, sorry for that. Being someone who uses Linux since 14 years, it seemed obvious to me that when executing commands using `sudo` or as root you have to exercise caution and actually *know* what you're doing and *check* what you're typing. I wanted to delete the question, but I recognize that this Q/A helps users with less experience so I'll just let it stand.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/149/).

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /<accidental enter>` Get the picture?

Comment: Mistakes arising from improper use of escalated permissions do not actually compromise "system security" that often, but system stability and data integrity are much easier and frequent targets. And the bug most likely to cause such mistakes is not in software, but of PEBCAK nature.

Comment: Principle of least privilege. You don't know that anything bad will happen, but you don't know that it *won't* either. If you're careful you'll limit your exposure to bad things. "Not typing sudo" doesn't sound like very hard work to me :)

Comment: If you blindly preface commands with `sudo` you risk finding yourself [in this guy's shoes](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The risk of a **typo** is more than the risk of a bug.

The risk of gaining a habit of "it doesn't work, stick `sudo` on it!" is much higher than the risk of a bug.

As a sysadmin who's seen people execute all sorts of random commands with `sudo` that didn't need them, I always caution against superfluous usage of `sudo`.

While `cat` isn't harmful, the habit that this encourages is.

Comment: Example: `sudo cat /etc/group` (harmless, but the sudo isn't needed) versus `sudo cat >/etc/group` (oops!).

Comment: @BenCrowell close (but `sudo` wouldn't apply on the redirection).

Comment: The habit of just adding `sudo` is indeed a very dangerous one. Rather one should stop and ask "why do I need sudo here?" And if you don't know a good reason, chances are you made some other mistake in the command. Just adding whatever it takes to make error messages go away lead you to mistakes like this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/587102/monday-morning-mistake-sudo-rm-rf-no-preserve-root (My favorite comment is the one asking "How do you even type --no-preserve-root accidentally?")

Comment: `svn update`. Eugh conflicts. I know. `sudo svn update`. I've actually seen this...

Comment: I don't use subversion but I'd guess that using something like `sudo svn update` would also completely mess up permissions - leaving you in a worse state than you were to start with.

Comment: @DaboRoss I think that should be included in @muru's answer, because this is one of the pitfalls of using `sudo`: you might end up creating files that are only accessible by invoking `sudo` again.

Comment: The risk of security problems, separate from typos, is actually bigger than one might think. See for example: http://lcamtuf.blogspot.ca/2014/10/psa-dont-run-strings-on-untrusted-files.html

Comment: A while ago I made a directory called `etc` in my home directory. To delete it again, I wanted to type `sudo rm -R ./etc` but I forgot the dot. Bye system.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Isn't the real problem giving people who shouldn't have sudo access sudo permission or not properly restricting their sudo access to prevent issues? In other words this sounds more like a management or sysadmin failure than a user failure unless they have been properly trained to mitigate these issues.

Comment: @flickerfly "this sounds" ... What sounds? That I don't have control over a user's personal laptop? (Mind you, the systems that I control have `sudo` properly configured. Doesn't stop users from trying, or from coming to me for help with personal systems). Most users are idiots. Even training can help only to an extent. Or are you saying Ubuntu shouldn't give full `sudo` access to the only account created on installation?

Comment: If the question is, "should the user use sudo or not?", which is what I understand it to be, I'm saying it is a policy decision. If the user is given it they should be able to use it at their discretion with provided permissions. It is the provider's responsibility to verify their ability to handle the responsibility. In the case of a personal system that is the same person. It isn't sudo's fault that the person messed up. That is a matter of trust and responsibility. sudo is just one place that will possibly cause failure of trust. The scope of the question wasn't limited to personal machines

Comment: @muru, Perhaps we can both agree that it is important to train people in the proper use of sudo and avoiding mistakes. My distinction is that it isn't sudo's fault that the person messes up. Blame should rest elsewhere. In other words, sudo isn't "Wrong" as the title states, but the person using it was wrong when they foul up my system or if I gave them access without knowing they could handle it properly, that's my fault (or management if it was beyond my control).

Comment: @flickerfly The question does ask what's wrong with `sudo`, but it really should be asking, 'what's wrong with unnecessary usage of `sudo`?', as the first sentence indicates. The debate is about gratuitous usage of `sudo` in guides and answers on AU. My position is that the person who uses `sudo` unnecessarily, leading others to believe it is okay to do so, is wrong.

Comment: @BenCrowell it is not so easy to redidrect with sudo

Comment: @muru, is it possible for `sudo cat filename` on a binary file to cause security issues, or does it just mess up your terminal the same way `cat binaryfile` does, necessitating a logout to reset the terminal?  In other words, are binary files an exception to your statement that `cat` isn't harmful?

Comment: @Wildcard AFAIK, it messes up the terminal the same way `cat binaryfile` does. Do you need a logout though? I find the `reset` command works well enough.

Answer (score 15):

I think there is another issue not yet mentioned: `sudo` status is cached for the shell with a default of 15 minutes. This means you don't have to provide your password in the next 15 minutes in order to execute a potentially dangerous command.

I think we all can think of more or less likely security issues that could result from that: Unknown software bugs that exploit this or forgetting to lock the screen with random people or co-workers around come to mind.

This is indeed my primary reason for not using `sudo` when I don't have to and even if I have to, for frequently closing shells after I'm done with `sudo` work.

Comment: That risk can be mitigated by using the `tty_tickets` option in `sudoers` and `sudo --remove-timestamp`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I already took `tty_tickets` into account. But you can set `timestamp_timeout`. That's why I wrote "default". I'm sure the majority of users will never change any of those options but of course that's speculation on my part.

Answer (score 9):

Using `sudo` excessively is the Linux equivalent of the old Windows habit of running everything under the Administrator account. *That* one has been discussed and criticized to hell and back, so you can read everything that talks about why a person should not be running their Windows computer as an Administrator, and every single point will apply to habitual use of `sudo` on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

well, it's just cause you might accidentally mess with sensitive parts of your file system, causing much much trouble to yourself
Being careful is never enough, so better not to expose yourself to unnecessary dangers

Answer (score -1):

When you do anything with **Sudo**, it means you give full rights to it, that's root access which is sometimes become very risky, if inadvertently, an app, which is running with root permission could do something wrong, results in a system crash to the corruption of the OS. Anyhow, for Cat, it's fine with root.

Comment: sudo can be configured to provide limited access. By default it provides an equivalent of full root access, but isn't required.

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with unnecessarily using Sudo. Sudo *(in it's default configuration/purpose on Ubuntu)* provides fully elevated privilidges. If a user has been granted those privilidges, they are his to exercise as he wishes *(including unnecessarily!)*. However, using Sudo when it isn't needed raises the stakes. It's an unnecessary risk. A simple typo can become disasterous, and that is why most people avoid using elevated permissions when they aren't needed. However, just because it is common practice to avoid unnecessary Sudo usage, doesn't mean it's wrong to go a different way. 
**Sudo to your heart's content!**

Within the context of AskUbuntu, I'm not at all surprised that you were instructed to avoid unnecessary Sudo usage. The purpose of this site is to allow experts to ask questions and get expert responses, but in reality there are lots of novice users on here, who know just enough to get themselves into trouble. It's common for posters to try and protect these users from themselves. Sudo abuse is common among novice users, because they don't really understand what is or does, nore take the time to learn. Also, this site prides itself on producing quality content. Unnecessary commands are inefficient, and therefore reduce the quality of a post.

Comment: **Bad advice:** *use sudo very carefully!* If you need sudo privileges it usually means you are doing something dangerous...

Comment: You do not use a missile to kill an ant. You always should use the correct tool and use it correctly.

Comment: @Fabby OP isn't suggesting one use Sudo unsafely, but rather pointing out that unnecessary usage doesn't equate to unsafe usage.

Comment: @Rinzwind There is nothing wrong with using a missle to kill an ant, so long as you're careful not to blow anything else up in the process. Unnecessary isn't a synonym for unsafe.

Comment: Yes there is. Example #1 http://askubuntu.com/questions/751339/attempted-to-open-unity-with-sudo-now-unity-messed-up

Comment: @HypnoToad While I personally avoid using Sudo if I don't need root permissions, and encourage others to do the same, you are correct. Unnecessary and unsafe are not the same thing. There is nothing wrong with using Sudo for every task you do, so long as you use it safely. But as said, I wouldn't suggest anyone do this, because it puts your system at unnecessary risk.

Comment: "Example #1" is irrelevant. This thread is about using Sudo when it isn't needed, not about abusing Sudo, as is the case in your example. If one cannot be trusted to use Sudo safely they shouldn't be a sudoer in the first place. For home users, this doesn't happen because they are administrating their own systems, which means, regardless of whether they have the knowledge to use Sudo safely they have access to it, and will be using it. To rehash, there is nothing wrong with using a missile to kill an ant, so long as you're careful not to blow up anything else up in the process.

Comment: You don't use a missile to kill an ant... unless it's Atom Ant!