# What is the complete command to be type in the command prompt to add the execute permission?

Tags: permissions, execute-command, convert-command

Help! I just need to know the complete command. To add the execute permission. Please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To give the execute permission to a shell script or the like, key in:

```
chmod +x /dir_path/file_name.sh
```

Make note, you'll need `sudo` for a file that is found in any of the system required folders.

For a further read into Linux permissions, click [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions). You'll find that there are two official ways of granting execute, as well as, more detail on how to formulate them.

Comment: `sudo` is not required in all cases. Try not to use [unnecessary `sudo`](http://askubuntu.com/q/545768/127327)

Comment: I think changing other permissions is not a good idea,i.e.,you are setting read+write permissions for group and others which is not desired here.The questioner asked only to add the 'executable' permission,For this the answer is simple "chmod +x <filename>" and also "sudo" is unnecessary.

Comment: I cant do it. Please help me. Can you teach me how. @Miphix Please . I need your help

Comment: Use "chmod +x filename" to add executable permission. @user369810

Comment: @user369810 for a file that is found in the /home/user369810/bin directry that is named FirewallAtHome.sh type in terminal $ chmod +x ~/bin/FirewallAtHome.sh Once you have assigned the execute permission, you'll find that it will execute. Also, you'll have to make sure that the file is found within path if you just want to type into terminal FirewallAtHome.sh in the terminal and have it execute. It's common practive to have a ./bin folder in the root directory of your home folder (Not '/'). For example, /home/user369810/bin. after you've made that file type in "$ echo $PATH"

Comment: @Miphix: What you did was too dangerous to let it be as other users who do not read the question well might get side-effects...  My apologies for the edit.

Comment: @Fabby it's ok. I would appreciate a note as to which dangerous command or action so as to correct my own understanding

Comment: 755 treats files and directories the same. Your command makes directories list-able and readable by all users (AND it also makes all files executable...)  ;-)

Comment: I didn't realize it was inherited. Is there documentation that would expand on this